Issue with AWS SDK 2.26.21 and Java 1.8 - How to Retrieve the Request ID for Support
We are using AWS SDK version 2.26.21 and Java 1.8.
When calling the headObject method from the S3Client class (software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client), which performs an operation in S3, we encounter the following exception:
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    ...

I need to retrieve the request ID to open a support ticket with AWS.
Is there a way to obtain the request ID using the AWS SDK?
I am not entirely sure, but could this information also be available through CloudTrail?

Java V2 s3.headObject() works fine. See this example
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectRestoreStatus.java
Also -- Modify your question, put your POM deps, you code, etc,
